# Phonegap application layout issue with soft keyboard in Android 2.3.6 and in iPhone 5.0

Tags: android, iphone, layout, cordova, keyboard

I created an application in html and JavaScript but it has the same bug is that with Android 2.3.6 with iPhone 5.0, while the Android version 4.0.4 the bug is not there.

To make it easier to explain my problem I put a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jamvq0idrhjdq9q/screenRecord.m4v) to the recording of my monitor.

The video on the iPhone, but on Android is the same. This application is for my thesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for showkeyboard/hidekeyboard events and resize your UI as appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what do you mean with "resize your UI"? I tried to use window.scrollTo(0,0) but doesn't work!!

Comment: You can use a different CSS sheet by using a media query to detect the screen size has changed. Then you can provide a different UI.